# How to pass/set "start" and "rows" parameter in @Query Solr Search

Tags: java, solr, lucene

As i can set text string in @Query(org.springframework.data.solr.repository.Query) Spring Solr Search.

But for pagination i need to set "start" and "rows" params in @Query?

Please suggest how to set these in @Query and use in Solr repositories.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define pagination options using the PageRequest[1] class which implements the Pageable[2] interface.

1. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html
2. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Is there any way to count total number of results using Pageable ?

Comment: You can use count method[http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/1.0.0.RC1/api/org/springframework/data/solr/core/SolrTemplate.html#count(org.springframework.data.solr.core.query.SolrDataQuery] in SolrTemplate to get total number of results. For more information. refer https://lucidworks.com/blog/2013/04/03/spring-data-solr-tutorial-dynamic-queries/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. As i am using annotations so I don't have SolrTemplate Object to call count() method